# Basic technique behind Google's logo today (5/1/2011)

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate magnifying glass on Web-page image (Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849438/how-to-simulate-magnifying-glass-on-web-page-image-javascript)

Just wondering about the basic ideas behind how to achieve Google's logo today with the magnifying glass. I can think of one way although it seems inefficient.....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two images. As a simplified view of the entire process, in the OnMouseOver event, the second GIF image is popped up and only the part inside the circle is made visible.