# Creating Magnifying Glass on website for text

Tags: html, web-applications, web, widget, magnify

I'm trying to find a HMTL code to create a magnifying glass that will magnify text on a website however I can only find codes for images.

Could anyone help me out please?  I'm not very code literate i'm afraid!

Comment: Maybe something like `on("click", function() { changeFontSizeWithCSS();});` ?

Comment: Are you trying to magnify the text you are hovering over? Or do you want to show the hovered text in a another div?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use a CSS hover command for your text to scale up or down. (to keep things simple)

Something like this:

```
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

BUT

If you are looking for a better explanation on the process, see @Andy 's answer to this question: [How to simulate magnifying glass on Web-page image (Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849438/how-to-simulate-magnifying-glass-on-web-page-image-javascript)

It goes more in depth on the creation of logic for a responsive magnifying glass feature across multiple web browsers. 
(also provides a great reference to get you more familiar with how html, css, and js work together)